# Ito formula applied to $\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t W_s ds $

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I got this expression and I have to calculate its differential by the Ito formula, $W_t$ denotes the Brownian motion:
$$\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t W_s ds $$

I calculate the derivative of $f(t,x)=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t x ds $ with respect to $t$ getting $\partial_t f=\frac{x}{t}-\frac{\int_0^t xds}{t^2}$ but I can't derive with respect to $x$: I only got $\partial_x f=( x\frac{\int_0^t ds}{t})'=(x\frac{t}{t})'=1 $ but I really don't think it is correct. 
Can you help me?

Comment: Is it $x(t)$? Otherwise its trivial as $f(x,t) = x$ giving $\partial_t f = 0$ and $\partial_x f = 1$.

Comment: From the answer I think $\partial_t$ is correct because the solution is this derivative times $dt$ but I can't get $\partial_x=0$

Comment: $\partial_xx=1$ should be incorrect, because Brownian Motion is nowhere differentiable itself.

Comment: @emcor I also think the same, so how can I apply Ito formula to this expression?

Comment: I dont know how to derive the integral w.r.t. $W$ but in general you would apply Ito Product Rule: $d(X_tY_t)=X_tdY_t+Y_tdX_t$ The only missing part would then be $dX_t=d(\int W_sds)$

Comment: I have already solved the same exercise with the product rule and i got the right result, but now i'm asked to solve it explicitly with the Ito formula...

Comment: Asking you to use Itô's formula is bizarre since this process has $C^1$ paths (on $t\gt0$) hence *usual* differentiation rules fully apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,

$$X_t := \int_0^t W_s \, ds \tag{1}$$

is an Itô process, i.e. an process of the form

$$Y_t - Y_0 = \int_0^t \sigma_s \, dW_s + \int_0^t b_s \, ds$$

(here $\sigma_t =0$, $b_t = W_t$). For an Itô process $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$ Itô's formula reads

$$f(Y_t)-f(Y_0) = \int_0^t f'(Y_s) \, dY_s +  \int_0^t f(Y_s) + \frac{1}{2} f''(Y_s) \, d \langle Y \rangle_s \tag{2}$$

where (by definition)

$$dY_t = \sigma_t \, dW_t + b_t \, dt \qquad \qquad d\langle Y \rangle_t = \sigma_t^2 \, dt.$$

Now note that $Y_t := (t,X_t)$ defines again an Itô process. If we apply $(2)$ and use $(1)$, we get that

$$f((t,X_t))-f((0,X_0)) = \int_0^t f_x((s,X_s)) W_s \, ds + \int_0^t f_t((s,X_s)) \, ds.$$

(Here $f_x$ denotes the derivative with respect to $x$ and $f_t$ the derivative with respect to $t$.) In particular, if we choose $f(t,x) := \frac{1}{t} \cdot x$ we find

$$\frac{1}{t} \int_0^t W_s \, ds = \int_0^t \frac{1}{s} W_s \, ds - \int_0^t \frac{1}{s^2} X_s \, ds.$$

---

**Remark** Note that Itô's formula is rather overkill. In fact, since $t \mapsto W_t$ continuous we see from fundamental theorem that $$t \mapsto X_t = \int_0^t W_s \, ds$$ is differentiable. Hence,

$$\frac{X_t}{t} = \int_0^t \left(\frac{d}{ds} \frac{X_s}{s} \right) \, ds$$

where, by the product rule,

$$\frac{d}{ds} \frac{X_s}{s} = - \frac{1}{s^2} X_s + \frac{W_s}{s}.$$

Comment: For the OP's understanding, you might want to add that the process has C1 paths (on t>0) hence usual differentiation rules fully apply.

Comment: @Did Can you explain why it has $C^1$ paths, from my understanding the Brownian Motion is nowhere differentiable?

Comment: @emcor The process of interest is not $(W_t)_t$ (nowhere differentiable) but $(\frac1tX_t)_t$ with $X=\int_0^.W$. Then, for every $t$, $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}X_t$ exists and $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}X_t=W_t$, which is continuous.

Comment: @Did ah ok, but then $\partial_t^2X_t$ would not exist (hence only $C^1$)?

Comment: @Did But I don't need this fact as long as I base the the proof on Itô's formula (and that was what the OP was asking for). In fact, Itô's formula is rather overkill in the given problem...

Comment: @emcor Exactly.

Comment: Hence the suggestion to signal that Itô is squarely offtopic here ("rather overkill", in your parlance). Which you did now.